# I can't seem to embed some of my html in my javascript correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function where I'm embedding html. I have a variable that I'm trying to call a toString method on. However, my page doesn't like the way I have my quotes I think. This is what I have:

```
function (item) {
    '<h3>' + item.StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + '</h3>'
}
```

Comment: It's `toString()` with a **lower-case "t"**.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: @Pointy: And it doesn't take arguments.  That looks like C# code.

Comment: Also use a variable and then embed the variable!

Comment: @SLaks it might be DateJS?  Guessing here ...

Comment: ... and function does not return or use the string... I'm tempted to vote to close...

Comment: How are you using this function? What do you expect it to do? What is is actually doing?

Comment: Yes, it is C# code. I just wanted to display my date variable on a page that is loaded with js. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it probably wants to look like:

```
function printMyItem(item) {
    return '<h3>' + item.StartDate.toString("MM/dd/yyyy") + '</h3>';
}

document.write(printMyItem());
```

Also the syntax is `toString` instead of `ToString`.

Something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are fine, but its `toString` not `ToString`.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if that 'StartDate' property wasn't an object with a function 'ToString(formatString)'